# Variable allocation and tracking

Tags: memory-management, data-structures, operating-system

I started searching and reading about ALDS and memory management recently after I got a doubt about memory allocation, and after a couple of days of study I learnt a lot of things about memory management but the actual doubt remains unsolved.

So the doubt is, while allocating memory to a variable, how exactly does the system know which block of memory is available and which is free, and similarly when we destruct an object or set a variable as null or when GC frees up some memory, what exactly does it do with that block of memory, as **I know the actual data is never erased on deletion, that block just gets marked as free somewhere in some table, but does that table keep track of each and every bit on the memory,** if yes then wouldn't that become a lot of data in itself to store?

For an example, if I declare a linked list, then a  block will be allocated in heap with it's next block having null value as there is no other node to reference, now as I keep adding more nodes into it, system will keep allocating more blocks each containing reference to next one. Now these blocks can be present on random locations depending on the availability of memory at allocation time, and can only be accessed through their proceeding nodes.

So now, for any given block of memory, how the system will know if its free and has just garbage value in it, or its actually a node of some linked list.

Answer (score 0):

On a modern operating system the process has a logical, linear address space. Part of that address space is reserved for the system and is common to all processes. Some of the address space may be reserved but most of the remainder is available to the process.

The address space is defined by PAGE TABLES. The structure of the page table is defined by the processor but the operating system maintains a table for each process. Memory is allocated to a process in PAGES. The smallest I am aware of is 512 bytes but the size can go up to a megabyte or even larger in some processors and some processor configurations.The size is always a power of 2.

The page table defines:

1. Whether an page has actually been mapped to the process
2. Whether the pages has a corresponding physical memory location
3. If so, the mapping to that physical location.

There operating system only knows about pages.

At the next level down there are memory managers. These are not part of the operating system. Memory managers manage heaps that consist of pages allocated by the operating system. The memory manage has to keep track of the heap size and what memory has been allocated within it.

Memory managers operate is a huge number of different ways. There are malloc/free implementations galore that you can link into your code to get different behaviors.

Comment: Is the memory in heap also allocated in the form of pages? As per my understanding, entire memory space is divided into heap and stack, stack is used to store actual application data i.e functions and constants etc. These are loaded and unloaded at the runtime in the form of pages. While heap memory is used to allocate blocks of memory needed by process at the runtime. And is freed up by garbage collector when not needed any more. So it's easier to keep track of "pages" as they address a large area of memory. While in heap, if I allocate only 1 byte block. How will that be tracked?

Comment: The memory space is not divided. There is just memory. The only thing that makes a heap a heap and a stack at stack is how it is allocated. All memory is allocated from the operating system in pages. A heap and stack can subdivide the pages and allocate from them smaller blocks of memory.